# Does there exists a Lebesgue integrable function where the set of discontinuities has positive measure

Tags: real-analysis

I am interested in the following question:  Does there exists a Lebesgue integrable function where the set of discontinuities has a positive measure?

I was thinking that this function, it exists, can be constructed as follows;
\begin{align}
f(x) =1_{S}(x)
\end{align}
where $S$ is some subset on $[0,1]$.
For example, if we take $S$ Cantor set then the number of discontinuities is dense, but still has measure zero. I was thinking maybe using a fat-Cantor set (Smith-Voltera-Cantor).

Comment: $f(x) = 1_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$

Comment: Also, the set of discontinuities of the characteristic function of a Cantor set is not dense.

Comment: @JoseAvilez  This function integrates to zero. Is there a function that integrated to a positive number?

Comment: @B.S.Thomson  I guess I should have written $S^c$, right?

Comment: @Lisa Take $f(x) = 1_{\mathbb{Q}^c \cap [0,1]}(x)$.

Comment: @JoseAvilez  The set $Q^c \cap [0,1]$ is the set of all irrational numbers on [0,1]?   I know that irrational numbers on [0,1]$ have measure one.  I guess I am not sure what is the set of discontinuities here. Can you clarify what is the set of discontinuties?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The discontinuities are all of $[0,1]$

Comment: @JoseAvilez One more question. Is this function almost surely equal to 1? It is right?